# Async for Bulk copy

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sqlbulkcopy

I have quite a few datatable to bulkinsert into databasetable
Due to its large size, one table took 5 min to complete the insert. 2 tables took me 10 min

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable1);
    DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable2);
}

public static void DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable Table){
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(myConnection);
    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DatabaseTable";
    myConnection.Open();                    
    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(Table);
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

I am now trying to do an async for Bulk insert, but there is neither any data inserted nor giving me error. How to capture the exception?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var insert1 = Task.Run(async () => await DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable1);
     var insert2 = Task.Run(async () => await DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable2);
     Task.WhenAll( insert1, insert2);
}

public static async Task<Boolean> DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable Table)
{
      try
      {
          SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(myConnection);
          sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DatabaseTable";
          myConnection.Open();                    
          await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(Table);
          myConnection.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception (e))
      {
        console.write(e);
      }
      return true;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a debugger on the line `console.write(e);`? In my experience async methods often swallows exceptions.

Comment: Use `Task.WaitAll(insert1, insert 2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Task.Run`s are adding nothing useful here. Also, don't try to share a single connection *object* between the two runs of your method. Something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var insert1 = DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable1);
     var insert2 = DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable2);
     Task.WaitAll( insert1, insert2);
}

public static async Task DataTableBulkInsert(DataTable Table)
{
      using(var localConnection = new SqlConnection(/* connection string */))
      {
          SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(localConnection );
          sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DatabaseTable";
          localConnection.Open();                    
          await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(Table);
      }
 }
```

Normally `return await` is an anti-pattern, but here you want to use it so that the `using` statement doesn't close your connection until after the bulk load is complete.

Also, I switched to using [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) which actually *waits*, which is more idiomatic than using `Task.WhenAll` and then immediately calling `Wait` on it.

Comment: _return await is an anti-pattern_ - Very interesting. Could you provide some more information regarding this?

Comment: @smoksnes - `await` is a way of pausing the current method until some other piece of code has done its job. If all that your method is going to do when it's resumed is to say "I'm done" then why did you go to all of the effort? That being said, the actual anti-pattern is `return await` if that's the *only* `await` in the method (as it is here) and it's not within a `try` block with a `finally` or a `using` block (in which case there is additional code to run after `return`)

Comment: @smoksnes - there's even a [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1981) asking for the compiler to optimize it out.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: Do I still need to return when your task do not have a object expression?
I have this error Task has no Object expression error with return

Comment: @Jonathan - I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

`Task.WhenAll` returns a Task object that needs to be awaited or the code that follows continues its normal execution and the main method exits immediately.

Since this is a console application and the main can't be marked as `async`, you can use this:

```
Task.WhenAll(insert1, insert2).Wait(); // wait for the returned Task object to Complete
```

The normal usage is: `await (Task.WhenAll(...))` but you can't mark Main as an `async` method.

Comment: It works after I added in the .Wait();
However, now I am getting connection open and close problem. How to allow one connection cater for multiple bulkcopy?

Comment: @Jonathan you might need to create a separate connection for each task. or close the connection after the `Task.WhenAll(insert1, insert2).Wait();` line of code.