# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity UserManager GetUserAsync

Tags: asp.net, async-await, task-parallel-library, asp.net-identity

I've been reading the source code of UserManager.cs and I've stepped into the following block:

```
        public virtual Task<TUser> GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
        }
        var id = GetUserId(principal);
        return id == null ? Task.FromResult<TUser>(null) : FindByIdAsync(id);
    }
```

I've been very curious if there is a reason why the above is not like this:

```
        public virtual async Task<TUser> GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
        }
        var id = GetUserId(principal);
        return id == null ? await Task.FromResult<TUser>(null) : await FindByIdAsync(id);
    }
```

As you can see I've only added async/await.

*I'm implementing the UserManager class with another ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I didn't write it I cannot know for certain. ;) But I guess it's regarding the `return await`-anti pattern.

There's even an issue for it on GitHub, where the request is that Roslyn handles it when compiling.

[Optimize an async method that ends "return await e" to be non-async "return e"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1981)

> this optimization would improve the performance of an async method
>   whose only await appears at the end. Not when producing debug code and
>   not when nested in a try block.

To quote the excellent comment from [damien_the_unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever), which he posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759458/async-for-bulk-copy/38759963#comment64892188_38759963)

> `await` is a way of pausing the current method until some other piece of
>   code has done its job. If all that your method is going to do when
>   it's resumed is to say "I'm done" then why did you go to all of the
>   effort? That being said, the actual anti-pattern is `return await` if
>   that's the *only* `await` in the method (as it is here) and it's not
>   within a `try` block with a `finally` or a `using` block (in which case
>   there is additional code to run after return

When using `await/async` one should be aware of the overhead it creates.

Take these two classes for example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public async Task<int> GetIdAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => 100);
    }
}

public class Foo : BaseClass
{
    public Task<int> GetId()
    {
        return GetIdAsync();
    }
}


public class Bar : BaseClass
{
    public async Task<int> GetId()
    {
        return await GetIdAsync();
    }
}
```

If you decompile the code from `Bar` with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) will look something like this:

```
public class Bar : BaseClass
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough, AsyncStateMachine(typeof(Bar.<GetId>d__0))]
    public Task<int> GetId()
    {
        Bar.<GetId>d__0 <GetId>d__ = new Bar.<GetId>d__0();
        <GetId>d__.<>4__this = this;
        <GetId>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Create();
        <GetId>d__.<>1__state = -1;
        AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int> <>t__builder = <GetId>d__.<>t__builder;
        <>t__builder.Start<Bar.<GetId>d__0>(ref <GetId>d__);
        return <GetId>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
    }
}
```

While `Foo` looks like this:

```
public class Foo : BaseClass
{
    public Task<int> GetId()
    {
        return base.GetIdAsync();
    }
}
```

So, to sum up, if you're simply going to return the value from one `Task`, there's really no reason to `await` it. Instead you should return the `Task` and let the *caller* `await` that `Task` instead. Awaiting the `Task` extends the stack and creates an overhead which only affects performance negatively.

Comment: And what about exception propagation. Async/await ensures continuation and allows the exception to be returned correctly.

Would it create a problem if i just Task and an exception is being thrown?

I tried finding a quick answer if async/await can jump the initial thread and continue with another one but i haven't yet clarified this.

Comment: The GitHub-link discusses the handling of exceptions. Returning the task would indeed alter the stack for the exception. The `Task` must still be awaited, so the exception should still returned, but probably in another stack.